# uninstall package in androidManifest.xml with activity and intent

Tags: android, installation, uninstallation

I want to uninstall old version of my app when installing new version of my app(I changed package name in new version of my app).
I add following code to androidManifest.xml but can not delete old version.

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="uninstallerOldVersionActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.UNINSTALL_PACKAGE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="com.ionicframework.discountnetmobile728945" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

permissions in androidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
```

how to uninstall app When installing new app ?

Answer (score 0):

You will be need Runtime class.You can use this method to uninstall old package.

```
    private void runShellCommand(String command) throws Exception {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    process.waitFor();
}
```

And call method like that :

```
runShellCommand("pm uninstall 'Package name of the old app'");
```